# Call matlab R2016a from vs 2008 c++

Tags: c++, c

I want to create a project where I can process the data in C ++ and display it using the force of matlab (plot).
as I mentioned in the title, I use matlab R2016a and the vs 2008 under windows 7. I followed a tutorial on YouTube (https://youtu.be/vQ5aIxCX3To), but unfortunately it did not work for me.I have as error lnk2019 and lnk1120.
I add those paths:

executable file: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64

Include file: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\include

Library file: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft

In the linker input, I add:

```
libmat.lib
libmx.lib
libmex.lib
libeng.lib
```

The code is as follow:

```
#include <Engine.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

#pragma comment (lib, "libmat.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "libmx.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "libmex.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "libeng.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Engine *m_pEngine;
    m_pEngine = engOpen("null");
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove engOpen, it will compile without errors, but when i add it, i will have error lnk2019 and lnk1120.

how to solve this kind of problem?